# Selecting all objects in the list of objects (in Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list, oop, object

I have issues with the following problem. I have a class, for example, defined like this:

```
class Example:
  def __init__(self,a):
    self.a = a
```

and now I create a list of instances, for example:

```
X = [Example(1) for i in range(5)]
```

Now, what I want to do is to access all the `a` values of all the instances in the list (at the same time), so that the result would be following:

```
>> [1,1,1,1,1]
```

that is, to be able to work with the list's instances' `a` like with standard vector/array/list. However, I struggle with understanding how to achieve this. What first came to my mind was to write:

```
X[:].a
```

but this indeed did not work. I am still a newbie when it comes to the Python, so I would like to ask you if there is any easy formula/trick how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
X[:].a
```

means "create a copy of the list `X`, then access the `a` attribute *of that list*" (which doesn't exist). Instead, you want something like:

```
[x.a for x in X]
```

which means "access the `a` attribute for each object `x` in the list `X`, and fill a new list with those values". In a more functional mood, you might write something like:

```
from operator import attrgetter

map(attrgetter('a'), X)
```

which will give the same result (in Python 2.x) as the list comprehension.

Comment: Ohh, thank you a lot :) this works just as I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Try list comprehension

```
[i.x for i in X]
```